# Is there a way of performing stratified cross validation using xgboost module in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, cross-validation

I am training and predicting on the same data-set, but I want to perform 10-fold cross-validation and predict on the left out fold and thus predict on the whole data set. How can I do this?

The libraries which I am using are:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
import xgboost as xgb
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is a typical example of k-fold cross validation.

`XGBoost` is just used for boosting the performance and signifies "distributed gradient boosting".

First, run the cross-validation step:

```
kfld = sklearn.cross_validation.KFold(labels.size, n_folds=10)
```

Then, use the train and test indices in `kfld` for constructing the XGBoost matrix and re-scaling weights by looping over them(the indices).

A very neat implementation has been given as a Kaggle example [here](https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/forum-message-attachments/44825/1290/test_xgboost.py?sv=2012-02-12&se=2015-12-14T21%3A28%3A18Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=yQJmvA%2FpUqve9EDdkF1bWAaYjEtNFmcUfjQUHaTTD7U%3D).

So, cross validation is not done with the `xgboost` package, it is done with the `cross_validation` module of `sklearn`, and then the gradient boosting is done on the indices of the k-fold validation variable results.

Answer (score 2):

xgboost comes with an own cv method, see an [example here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/cross_validation.py)